# Font and Alignment script not running

Tags: excel, fonts, alignment

I have a spreadsheet that has information entered by multiple people on multiple devices and different font settings. I would like a simple script to change all pages of the spreadsheet, (3 on test but actually 5 pages on original). Preferably on any edit, but when you switch from page to page within the sheet would be fine.

Here is link to spreadsheet:-
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hUSgX4Teg71sgI6AUlxgY7HCatUTAszP3M4f6o_eyMU/edit?usp=sharing

My script below:-

```
function onOpen()   {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheets();

    var cell = sheet.getRange("C6:P26");
    cell.setFontSize(12);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment("center");
}
```

I have tried onEdit too but still not working but debugger is not throwing up errors just not running.  Not sure if it is the Range option as it doesn't select the correct area in each sheet, should I make 1 per sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code after many tries.

```
function onEdit()   {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets(); 
  var cell = ss.getRange("C6:U39");
      cell.setFontSize(12);
     cell.setHorizontalAlignment("center");


}
```